# Moving from Scilab to C++

Tags: c++, math, vector, matrix

I'm working on a project that needs to perform a variety of mathematical operations, which are native to languages ​​such as scilab, matlab, octave. So I'm looking for a good library (preferably an open source library) that supports C++ and good performance. It should have the following features:

- it should support vector math (so it should allow you to easily define vectors and matrices, and operations between them, etc.);
- it should allow you to generate random numbers using normal or uniform distributions (both unidimensional and bidimensional distributions);
- it should allow to comfortably perform other operations such as the cumulative sum, the division of a vector (ie all its elements) for the same value, etc..

I read about [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), but I did not find examples that explain how to use these features: I'm looking for a guide like "Boost C++ for scilab programmers"...

Comment: Who's downvoting you? What for?

Comment: I heard good things of [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), but I don't know if it supports the operations you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) supports matrices and vectors as well as a random number generator class.

[Matrix](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) class

[Vector](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec) class

[RNG](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#rng) class

Comment: And what about matrix-vector and vector-scalar operations?

Answer (score 1):

`Eigen` is a good matrix and Vector library that covers points 1 and 3. As for point 2 there are plenty of random libraries. In fact you can also easily write your own like this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/7445/

Hope this helps.

PS. Link to Eigen here:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: You may also wish to try [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net), which is a related C++ matrix library designed with ease of use in mind.